# Why use @before for class variable reinitilization, when junit itself re-initialized class for every test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit

Junit re-initializes class and variable for every test. So why is it preferred to initialized class variable inside @before annotated methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you already said there are two common ways of instantiating fields of a test class in JUnit 4. (This is still valid for JUnit Jupiter as long as you don't use `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`.) Either people initialize them immediately

```
public class SomeTest {
    private final FirstType someFirstType = new FirstType(...);
    private final SecondType someSecondType = new SecondType(...);

    @Test
    public void someTest {

    ...
}
```

or they are using a setup method

```
public class SomeTest {
    private FirstType someFirstType;
    private SecondType someSecondType;

    @Before
    public void createObjects() throws Exception {
        someFirstType = new FirstType(...);
        someSecondType = new SecondType(...);
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest {

    ...
}
```

In the end both styles lead to the same result: every test runs with its own instances of `someFirstType` and `someSecondType`. However both styles have unique advantages

#### Immediate Initialization

- Initialisation of fields is close to their declaration. (Improves readability because the reader does not have to find the initialisation code.)
- Fields could be final so that it is obvious that they are not reassigned.

#### Setup Method

- Fields can be initialized by constructors that throw checked exceptions.
- You can run code that calculates objects which are afterwards used to call the constructor. E.g.

  ```
  @Before
  public void createObjects() throws Exception {
      int[] someNumbers = new int[10];
      for (int i = 0; i < someNumbers.length; ++i) {
          someNumbers[i] = i*i;
      }
      someFirstType = new FirstType(someNumbers);
  }
  ```